# Is 何歳ですか polite?

Tags: politeness, questions

## 何歳ですか (なんさいですか) - How old are you?

Is it usual for Japanese to ask each other how old they are, and if it is, how do they go about and ask it? Is there a polite way to ask, or do you not ask this at all, or are you only able to ask this after you get close with the person you want to ask this?

Comment: Not polite at all.  Been wondering why they teach you to say it in JPN as a foreign language.

Answer (score 1):

Typically one asks おいくつですか？　(or possibly a more polite variant)

In a format situation (notwistanding that asking someone's age is likely inappropriate) 何歳ですか？ is probably not the best way.